# Converting Java Code to a UML diagram

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram, model-associations

I have to convert the following Java code to a UML diagram, however I'm not sure whether I have done the associations between the classes correctly. Please you advise me whether or not the UML diagram is correct.

```
public class Booking {

    private String name;

    private Time time;

    private Table[] tables;

    public Booking ( String n, int st, int en, int num ){
    }

    public int getStart (  ){
        return 1;
    }

    public int getEnd (  ){
        return 1;
    }

    public Table[] getTables (  ){
        return new Table[3];
    }

    public int getBookingSize (  ){
        return 1;
    }
}
```

```
public class Time {

    private int startHour;

    private int endHour;

    public Time ( int st, int en ){
    }

    public int getStart (  ){
        return 1;
    }

    public int getEnd (  ){
        return 1;
    }
}
```

```
public class Table {

    private int number;

    private int seats;

    public Table ( int num, int sz ){
    }

    public int getNumber (  ){
        return 1;
    }

    public int getSeats (  ){
        return 1;
    }
}
```

```
public class Restaurant {

    private Booking[] bookings;

    public void makeBooking ( String n, int st, int en, int s ){
    }


    public void cancelBooking ( String n ){
    }

    public Table[] getTables ( String n ){
        return new Table[2];
    }

    public int getStTime (String n) {
        return 1;
    }

    public int getEndTime (String n) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should review your cardinalities - like, `Booking` references an array of `Table` in your code but is shown as a `1:1` relationship in the diagram. Similarly, `Booking` references `Time` once in the code but is shown as 1:n relationship in the diagram. Also, I do not see any direct relationship from `Restaurant` to `Time` in the code.

Comment: But the methods public int getStTime (String n) and public int getEndTime (String n) are contained within the Restaurant code so isn't there is a direct relationship from Restaurant to Time?

Comment: I would say, it is **not** a **direct** relationship in any case - it is probably a **conceptual** relationship (these methods look like convenient methods to get start and end time for a given booking, but that could also be solved by returning a given `Booking` and use the `getStart()` and `getEnd()` methods of that class). It somewhat depends on what your intention is with that UML diagram - if its intended to most perfectly reflect the Java code the relationship is not there, if it shall show a conceptual model you could probably add it.

Comment: Maybe the relationship from `Restaurant` to `Time` is to represent opening hours?

Answer (score 1):

I will ignore methods and attributes, because they are trivial and not interesting (and getters should ideally be omitted).

[image]

There are several differences to your diagram:

- `Restaurant` may not have any bookings at all, so it should be `*`, and not `1..*`
- `Booking` needs only one `Time`, because `Time` already contains the start and end
- I don't know why `Restaurant` has start and end time. I will assume it's to show opening hours (which is a single instance of a `Time`.
- According to your code you can have `Booking` on more than one `Table`. In your diagram only one was possible.
- One `Table` may have many `Booking`s. In your diagram it could have only one. (Of course there is run-time constraint that two `Booking`s shouldn't book the same `Table` within the same `Time` period, but that should be expressed in OCL or as a note)
- Added role names to the association endpoints (`period`,`openingHours`,...)

More notes:

- `Time` should either contain a single time, or it should be renamed to `Period` or `TimeInterval`. The current naming is confusing.
- Multiplicity on the other side of relations from `Time` can be omitted (since they do not have much meaning here).

Comment: Well, you make corrections to the source code (which is poor, yes). But the question is to provide the correct UML for the source.

Comment: @ThomasKilian apart from the `Restaurant`-`Time` association I do not see any discrepancies. (Especially considering that the provided implementation makes very little sense.)

Comment: I think that you should point out that the openingHours were added by you intentionally and are not part of the shown code.

Answer (score -1):

```
 +------------------+                     +--------------------+
 |  Input Text     |                     |  Pre-processing   |
 | (Plant Symptoms)|                     | (Tokenization,    |
 |                  |                     |  Embedding, etc.) |
 +--------+---------+                     +--------+-----------+
          |                                          |
 +--------v-----------+         +--------------------v-------------+
 |  Language Model    |         |    Convolutional Neural Network  |
 | (ULM)               |         |       (CNN) for Image Analysis  |
 |                     |         |                                |
 |    +------------+   |         |   +-------------+  +--------+ |
 |    | LSTM Layer |   |         |   | Convolution |  | Fully  | |
 |    | 1          |   |         |   |  Layers     |  |   Connected| |
 |    +------------+   |         |   +-------------+  |  Layers  | |
 |          |          |         |            |        +----------+ |
 |    +-----v-----+    |         |   +--------v-------+            |
 |    | LSTM Layer |    |         |   |   Pooling Layer |            |
 |    | 2          |    |         |   |    (e.g. Max)    |            |
 |    +------------+    |         |   +------------------+            |
 |          |          |         |            |                       |
 |    +-----v-----+    |         |   +--------v-------+            |
 |    | LSTM Layer |    |         |   |  Flatten Layer  |            |
 |    | 3          |    |         |   +------------------+            |
 |    +------------+    |         |            |                       |
 |          |          |         |   +--------v-------+            |
 |    +-----v-----+    |         |   | Fully Connected |            |
 |    |  Output    |    |         |   |    Layers for    |            |
 |    |  Layer     |    |         |   |  Classification  |            |
 |    +------------+    |         |   +------------------+            |
 |          |          |         |            |                       |
 +----------v----------+         +------------v-----------------------+
            |                                      |
 +----------v----------+                           |
 |  Softmax Activation |                           |
 |  (Output Probabilities)|                        |
 +----------------------+                           |
                                                  |
                                    +------------v----------------+
                                    |    Disease Prediction    |
                                    |    (e.g. Healthy,       |
                                    |     Diseased, etc.)     |
                                    +--------------------------+
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).